# Slicer Filtering on Drill-through Field Not Working

Tags: powerbi

I'm creating a report displaying the product quantity in warehouses at the end of each month. I have a measure that calculates this correctly, and it matches our system data. My bar chart shows the product quantity (y-axis) over time by month (x-axis).

However, when I add "Product Category" to the x-axis and use a slicer to filter the category, the filter affects the product calculation but doesn't change the "Product Category" display. It keeps showing all categories.

Goal:

How can I make my report filter all fields on the x-axis (both months and product categories) according to my slicer selections?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?